# Is the moment-generating-functns tag spelled wrong on purpose?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wikis, character-limit

The [moment-generating-functns](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/moment-generating-functns/info)-tag seems to be spelled incorrectly.

However, it could be due to a limit on the number of used characters, but since I couldn't find anything on it, I just wanted to let you guys know.

Comment: Yes, there's a 25 character limit for tag names.

Comment: @DanielFischer All right, thanks! I'll leave this question be, as a reference for people wondering the same in the future.

Comment: I guess I'll make it an answer then.

Comment: [Declined feature request to raise the length on Über-meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags)

Comment: See also the [tag-info for character-limit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/character-limit/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>There is a limit of 25 characters for the length of tag names, and the hyphens count. The proper name [moment-generating-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-functions) is two characters too long, so two characters were dropped in such a manner that the tag name is still understandable.</del>

The character limit was increased, so it was possible to create the tag with the proper name. [moment-generating-functns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-functns) was merged into [moment-generating-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-functions), yay.